# Android: Memory not being free'd after releasing references

Tags: java, android, performance, memory

I have an activity which I obtain a large list of objects, approx 25,000 objects containing about 600,000 strings in total, this comsumes around 20MB of the heap. This list is loaded into an `adapter` for a `recyclerview` which then displays the list.

My problem is that when I close the activity and the activity is supposedly 'destroyed', the huge list of objects is not garbage collected. Therefore my heap still contains the 20MB of objects and when I reopen that activity, another 20MB of objects is added to the heap and the memory is quickly eaten up.

Within the `onDestroy()` method of the activity, I attempt to release the reference to the `adapter` which contains the huge list of objects. I also release the reference to the `recyclerView` and `viewModel`, the viewModel is where I obtain the words from a `LiveData` object which updates the `adapter`.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    adapter = null;
    recyclerView = null;
    viewModel = null;
    Log.d("kesD", "onDestroy: pls free up my MB");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Although this isn't working and it appears that the 20MB of objects are not being removed from the heap, as shown in this console output below:

(emphasis on the **57MB/81MB** shown before **and** after destroying the activity and releasing the objects)

```
2020-02-05 20:18:36.349 2042-2077/co.uk.SpeedSpanish I/uk.SpeedSpanis: Background concurrent copying GC freed 461591(31MB) AllocSpace objects, 6(312KB) LOS objects, 29% free, 57MB/81MB, paused 151us total 238.203ms
2020-02-05 20:18:36.443 2042-2042/co.uk.SpeedSpanish D/kesD: onDestroy: pls free up my MB
2020-02-05 20:18:37.198 2042-2077/co.uk.SpeedSpanish I/uk.SpeedSpanis: Background concurrent copying GC freed 445259(31MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 29% free, 56MB/80MB, paused 98us total 240.906ms
```

I've made sure that there are no static references to the activity which may be keeping it (and my list of objects) alive.

The list of objects is not refered to statically anywhere, but I do filter the list with a static method within a different thread as seen below:

```
private void getViewModelAllWords(){
    viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(WordViewModel.class);
    adapter = new WordDetailedAdapter(this, viewModel, this, this, false);
    viewModel.getAllWordsLive().observe(this,words -> {
        Collections.sort(words, (o1, o2) -> o1.getWord().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getWord()));
        filterWords(words);
    });
}

private void filterWords(List<Word> words) {
    FilterThread thread = new FilterThread(words);
    thread.start();
}

private class FilterThread extends Thread{

    private List<Word> allWords;

    public FilterThread(List<Word> allWords){
        this.allWords = allWords;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(allWords!=null){
            final List<Word> words = WordFilter.getFilteredList(allWords, wordClassStr, wordCategoryStr);
            runOnUiThread(() -> applyFilteredWords(words));
            allWords = null;
        }
    }
}

private void applyFilteredWords(List<Word> words){
    adapter.submitList(words);
}

@Query("SELECT * FROM Word ORDER BY word")
LiveData<List<Word>> getAllWordsLive();
```

I also release the reference to the list after filtering it so this shouldn't be problematic.

Comment: This sounds like a job for [Dump Java heap](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/memory-profiler#capture-heap-dump).

Comment: please show how you load the list

Comment: @LenaBru I've added some more code to demonstrate where the list comes from.

Comment: How is getAllWordsLive() obtained?

Comment: @LenaBru it's a LiveData<List<Word>> object, which uses a `SELECT *` SQL statement to get the list from my Room database.

Comment: why don't you sort the list when selecting it, instead of sorting it programmatically, which would mean a bunch of code be removed that sorts it
I actually wanted to see the select statement

Comment: @LenaBru ok, but that's unrelated to the issue. The select statement has been added to the question for you.

Comment: are you releasing the observer after you're done with it?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you send something to be garbage collected, it might not necessarily be garbage collected immediately, or all at once.

With that, you need to check ALL the sources which hold your huge list.
In most cases it is held not only in the adapter.